# OVF disk formats

Tags: rhel5, vmware-vmdk, ovf

I thought that VMs exported as OVF were supposed to be completely portable, but now I see there are difference disk formats

I used the [VMware ovf tool](http://www.VMware.com/support/developer/ovf/) to export a VMX to OVF.  The disk file created with the OVF is a VMDK.

I want to import the VM into RHEV, but the [Red Hat documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization_for_Servers/2.2/HTML/Administration_Guide/Disks.HTML) says that the accepted disk formats are *RAW* and *COW*.  In contrast the VMware OVF tool says it can export to: *monolithicSparse*, *monolithicFlat*, *twoGbMaxExtentSparse*, *twoGbMaxExtentFlat*, *streamOptimized*, *thin* (vSphere target), *thick* (vSphere target).

How can I convert my VMDK OVF to a RAW OVF and then import it to RHEV?  The documented virt-v2v tool seems to only work with VMware ESX, not vmx/vmdk/ovf images on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Try [qemu-img](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img), it supports various formats for input and input.

In a last try, you can finally mount the disk on a VM and `tar` or `dd` it to another place, more friendly to other tools.

Comment: Good idea, tried it, but it keeps generating an error: 'qemu-img: error while reading'.  Have tried various vmware ovftool export options for the disk format, but no change. (would vote up but I have insufficient reputation)

Comment: @user updated the answer with another suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

OVF is basically an XML file that *describes* a VM, it doesn't contain it. There is a supported solution for moving VMs from VMWare, `called virt-v2v`.

The raw and cow formats are open formats supported by qemu, while all the vmware options are based on vmware's vmdk format.

This guide has a good description of the way virt-v2v should be used: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization_for_Servers/2.2/html/Administration_Guide/virt-v2v-scripts.html

Comment: The VMDK format is mostly "open" as well - the specification is available without a license to implementors. You do have to "request" access though. http://www.vmware.com/technical-resources/interfaces/vmdk.html. I beleive the same is true of the Microsoft/Xen .VHD format.

Comment: qemu supports vmdk, however it's quite common for it not to be able to recognise a vmdk that originates from a vmware setup. I guess the format specifications are not strictly adhered to